# Fcron says Job Completed , but not getting output

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to run a test fcron but failing to get proper output.
In the status i am able to see the job completion log. but i am not seeing the output created.

Fcrontab entry

```
shell=/bin/bash
path=/sbin:/bin/:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
home=/
mailto=''
15 10 * * * echo success > ~/test.txt
```

and the status log

```
Mar 29 10:15:00 3c fcron[1406]: Job 'echo success > ~/test.txt' started for user root (pid 1407)
Mar 29 10:15:00 3c fcron[1406]: Job 'echo success > ~/test.txt' completed
```

how to fix this. do i need to set any permissions? or is my fcron script  wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The test.txt will be in your HOME directory.